# All list elements being re-rendered on each change to the data array, despite unique keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building some chat application. I have a "Chat" container, which renders a "Message" component, for each element received from a Redux prop. Seemingly very simple.

This is the JSX that renders the Message component:

```
<div className="messages" >
                    <ul  >
                        {this.props.items.length > 0 && <i style={{ float: 'right' }} onClick={this.clearItems} data-toggle="tooltip" title="Clear history" className="fa fa-trash hover"></i>}

                        {this.props.items.map((message) => {

                            return <Message
                                showCheckBox={this.state.bulkOperationActive}
                                onBulkOperationOn={this.bulkOperationOn}
                                onDelete={this.deleteItems}
                                onItemCheck={this.onItemCheck}
                                checked={this.state.selectedItems.hasOwnProperty(message.itemId)}
                                key={message.itemId}
                                displayName={this.getDisplayName(message)}
                                time={this.getTime(message.moment)}
                                message={message}
                            />


                        })}
                    </ul>

                </div>
```

As you can see, i'm providing a unique key(message.itemId). Despite that, every time an item is added to the array(either by submitting a new message, or a message being received), **all Message components get re-rendered(i see it by placing a console.log in the render method)**.

This becomes very slow, after about lets say 100-150 items. I aint  a React pro, but from my understanding, the whole idea of the unique key is to prevent React from re-rendering items that didn't change.

Could someone give me a direction, as to what might be wrong? I will mention that the Message component is actually a wrapper to other simple functional components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Message Component should extends **`React.PureComponent`**.It will do shallow comparision of each prop and state and will re-render only if they changes.

Link to Pure Components :- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

I have Prepared a Demo for this :- https://codesandbox.io/s/34287lppzp.

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!

Comment: Holy smokes! it works :D Thank you, and i will certainly learn the subject, to understand the difference between a "normal" component and a pure one. However, i will mention that something here is still strange: When looking in the React virtual DOM in dev-tools, i do not see any element with a "key"(Both with Pure and normal component). As if my key prop doesn't exist(but i don't get any warning) What could be causing this?

Comment: You will not see "Key" as a prop in React Dev Tool because it is used internally ..the value passed in key will never be displayed in another component as {this.props.key} because it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

render get called for each of the sub components and it is normal, you can check Chrome element inspector to see what happens on DOM. take a look at [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Every time props or state is changed component will re-render .
To stop re-rendering use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`.

Comment: Well yeah, but the props of the Message component didn't change.